# I am getting an Error on this even after adding an alias.... why?

Tags: postgresql, alias, derived-table

```
SELECT * FROM 

(select 
flight_id,
flight_no,
scheduled_departure,
scheduled_arrival,
cast (scheduled_departure as text) TIMINGS
from bookings.flights), as TABLE1

case when TIMINGS
between 02:00:00+05:30 to 06:00:00+05:30 then 'Early morning flights'
when scheduled_departure to scheduled_arrival 

between 06:00:00+05:30  to 11:00:00+05:30 then 'Morning flights'
when scheduled_departure to scheduled_arrival 

between 11:00:00+05:30 to 16:00:00+05:30 then 'Noon flights'
when scheduled_departure to scheduled_arrival 

between 16:00:00+05:30 to 19:00:00+05:30 then 'Evening flights'
when scheduled_departure to scheduled_arrival 

between 19:00:00+05:30 to 23:00:00+05:30 then 'Night flights'
when scheduled_departure to scheduled_arrival 

between 23:00:00+05:30 to 02:00:00+05;30  then 'Night flights'
END as TIMINGS
```

This is the ERROR

```
ERROR:  subquery in FROM must have an alias
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM (select 
                      ^
HINT:  For example, FROM (SELECT ...) [AS] foo.
SQL state: 42601
Character: 15
```

Comment: You need to get rid of the `,` before the `AS TABLE1` - but the CASE expression will then be your next problem.

Comment: Yes i did try removing that but it gave me a different error

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name how do I solve the CASE expression Error?

Comment: A CASE expression needs to go into the SELECT list. You can't have that in the FROM clause

Comment: Any Alternate way to get the required Output?

Answer (score 0):

You can get what you are looking for without [CASE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-CASE) at all.  
One thing to realize is when working with dates/timestamps converting to text is virtually always unnecessary and incorrect (as is the case here) basically just do not do it.  Use the [Postgres date functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html).

The following gives what you are wanting. It begins creating a CTE to define time periods and a descriptive name for each period. It then JOINS that CTE with the flight table. (See demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=3221a4e00543460e8de564561bf6451c))

```
with departures( stime, etime, description)  as 
     (values ('00:00:00'::time, '02:00:00'::time, 'Night flight') 
           , ('02:00:00'::time, '06:00:00'::time, 'Early morning flight')
           , ('06:00:00'::time, '11:00:00'::time, 'Morning flight')
           , ('11:00:00'::time, '16:00:00'::time, 'Noon flight')
           , ('16:00:00'::time, '19:00:00'::time, 'Evening flight')
           , ('19:00:00'::time, '24:00:00'::time, 'Night flight')
     )
select f.flight_id                                        "Flight Id" 
     , (f.departure at time zone 'Asia/Kolkata')::time(0) "Schedule Departure Time" 
     , d.description                                      "Description" 
   from departures d
   join flights    f 
     on (   (f.departure at time zone 'Asia/Kolkata')::time(0) >= d.stime 
        and (f.departure at time zone 'Asia/Kolkata')::time(0) <  d.etime 
        )
 order by  "Schedule Departure Time";
```

**Notes:**

- Timestamps always include a date and fractional seconds. Since you
  want just time comparisons both need to be discarded. This is
  accomplished with `::time(0)`. It does, however, round to the nearest
  second.
- I changed your definition for 'Night Flight'. In a timestamp, after
  discarding the date the resulting time,`23:00:00` will *always* be
  greater than `02:00:00`. The change corrects for this.
- I used *at time zone 'Asia/Kolkata'* to get your +3.5 hour
  offset from UTC (am at UTC-5). Depending on your server time zone
  setting you may not require this.

I am a newbie so bear with me if the format is not structured.
so I got the expected output after writing this code...

```
'''
with flights ( stime, etime, description)  as 
     (values ('00:00:00'::time, '02:00:00'::time, 'Night flight') 
           , ('02:00:00'::time, '06:00:00'::time, 'Early morning flight')
           , ('06:00:00'::time, '11:00:00'::time, 'Morning flight')
           , ('11:00:00'::time, '16:00:00'::time, 'Noon flight')
           , ('16:00:00'::time, '19:00:00'::time, 'Evening flight')
           , ('19:00:00'::time, '24:00:00'::time, 'Night flight')
      )
      select flight_id               "Filght ID"
      ,     flight_no                "Flight No"
      ,     scheduled_departure      "scheduled_departure"
      ,     scheduled_arrival        "scheduled_arrival"
      ,     flights                  "Timings"
      from flights  
      join bookings.flights    f 
     on (   (scheduled_departure at time zone 'Asia/Kolkata')::time(0) >= stime 
        and (scheduled_arrival at time zone 'Asia/Kolkata')::time(0) <  time 
        )
```

'''
but in the modified column I just want the Text such as 'Night Flight' instead of the entire time which is '00:00:00'::time, '02:00:00'::time, 'Night flight'
how can I get just the text output?

2nd I tried to filter the output using `having'`or `where` statement
using this code

```
 with flights ( stime, etime, description)  as 
     (values ('00:00:00'::time, '02:00:00'::time, 'Night flight') 
           , ('02:00:00'::time, '06:00:00'::time, 'Early morning flight')
           , ('06:00:00'::time, '11:00:00'::time, 'Morning flight')
           , ('11:00:00'::time, '16:00:00'::time, 'Noon flight')
           , ('16:00:00'::time, '19:00:00'::time, 'Evening flight')
           , ('19:00:00'::time, '24:00:00'::time, 'Night flight')
      )
      select flight_id               "Filght ID"
      ,     flight_no                "Flight No"
      ,     scheduled_departure      "scheduled_departure"
      ,     scheduled_arrival        "scheduled_arrival"
      ,     flights                  "Timings"
      from flights  
      join bookings.flights    f 
     on (   (scheduled_departure at time zone 'Asia/Kolkata')::time(0) >= stime 
        and (scheduled_arrival at time zone 'Asia/Kolkata')::time(0) <  etime 
        )
        group by 
        flight_id,
        flights 
having flights = 'Morning flight'
```

it is giving me an error saying this

ERROR:  input of anonymous composite types is not implemented
LINE 22: having flights = 'Morning flight'

(Pasting text because image is allowed in my account)

@belayer

---

Response:

- First Issue, unwanted columns: You only want *want the Text such as 'Night Flight' instead of the entire time*. Well each column is
  individually SELECTed in the query. If there are some you do not want then just remove them from the select list.
- Second issue: `flights = 'Morning flight`, `flights` refers to the
  entire set on rows within the CTE. The usage would be the same as if there were a table `flights`, you would not say `table_name = string`. In this case you are looking for `flights.description = 'Morning flight`. You will get a similar error on the line aliased as "Timings". You will need to refer to the individual columns.
- Third Issue: Filtering. The target column of HAVING is typically the result of an [aggregate](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-agg.html) column. However, your query has no
  aggregate function, so WHERE is appropriate. (Note the structure change. You can google *SQL Order of Operations*. So:

```
    with flights ( stime, etime, description)  as 
             (values ('00:00:00'::time, '02:00:00'::time, 'Night flight') 
                   , ('02:00:00'::time, '06:00:00'::time, 'Early morning flight')
                   , ('06:00:00'::time, '11:00:00'::time, 'Morning flight')
                   , ('11:00:00'::time, '16:00:00'::time, 'Noon flight')
                   , ('16:00:00'::time, '19:00:00'::time, 'Evening flight')
                   , ('19:00:00'::time, '24:00:00'::time, 'Night flight')
              )
              select flight_id               "Filght ID"
              ,     flight_no                "Flight No"
              ,     scheduled_departure      "scheduled_departure"
              ,     scheduled_arrival        "scheduled_arrival"
              ,     flights.description      "Timings"   -- ?? Guessing 
              from flights  
              join bookings.flights    f 
             on (   (scheduled_departure at time zone 'Asia/Kolkata')::time(0) >= stime 
                and (scheduled_arrival at time zone 'Asia/Kolkata')::time(0) <  etime 
                )
        Where flights.description = 'Morning flight';
```

Comment: Thank you so much this was a big help. learned a lot about Date/Timestamps through this answer.

Comment: I have almost got the expected out after applying the query above. one thing I wanted to ask was how can I apply 'where' or 'having' function to filter the results of the last column and when I did try it was giving me the error saying "cannot compare dissimilar column types text and unknown at record column" how to solve that?

Comment: Without seeing the query and specifically the clause giving the error there is no way to answer. Update the question to show the complete query and the complete error message. BTW that is not a Postgres error message or at least not a complete message.

Comment: When requesting clarification or indicating issues with an answer Update the original question. Do not update the answer. Instead indicate an edit in the question then post a comment to (after) the answer indicating such. The reason you are submitting your question to a large community of potential respondents. The individual providing the a successful answer may not be the same as the initial.Most will read your question completely but not necessary the answers. When you update an answer you greatly decrease potential respondents

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by *(Pasting text because image is allowed in my account)*. But for SO basic rule *only post image to help explain the text*, **text is always preferred**.

Comment: I will surely keep that in mind the next time I ask or edit the questions. Thanks much for the clarification.  The query is exactly what I expected so thanks for that as well.